# All through the Seasons - What am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

I go in a cup,
but you can't drink me up,
I soar through the air,
well above your hair,
At first I have need
of some serious speed.
Later, it's nice
to be more concise.
To the club we could go
if it doesn't snow
If I go to the beach
You will probably screech.

Edit: changed "don't" to "you can't" on line two to clarify.

Hint 1:

> This is a physical object you can touch and hold in your hand.

Comment: Another nice riddle! +1

Comment: Are things like "in a cup", "at first", "later" wordplay (as in your other riddle) or metaphor?

Comment: I could be totally wrong but I think  is the 4 states of the matter.

Comment: No wordplay this time. Literal clues at the start with some more metaphorical clues at the end.

Comment: Not the 4 states of matter. I'm not that deep a thinker today.

Comment: "well over your hair" would scan a little better on the fourth line.  Apart from that, and possibly "precise" instead of "concise", I really like this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The hint (and change of wording) helped.

You are:

> A golf ball

I go in a cup,
but you can't drink me up,

> A golf ball goes into the "cup" on the green, but obviously you don't drink golf balls

I soar through the air,
well above your hair,

> Pretty much any golf shot (except a putt or a very low chip) will go up in the air higher than a person

At first I have need
of some serious speed.

> The first golf shot off the tee goes very fast (can be 100+ MPH even for amateurs)

Later, it's nice
to be more concise.

> Putts are much more controlled shots and don't go NEARLY as fast

To the club we could go
if it doesn't snow

> You can't go to the country club and play golf if it's snowing

If I go to the beach
You will probably screech.

> You're upset if you land in a sand trap. At least I'm upset when *I* land in a sand trap.

Comment: Very nice. I also wanted club to reference what you might hit the answer with, and the title to be a little bit of a joke at how much these are used. "Come rain or shine."

Answer (score 3):

It could be

> WW2 Fighter-plane Spitfire

I go in a cup,
but you can't drink me up,

> Cup can be hangar where you store your Spitfires (hey, golf holes aren't called cups either). And you obviously can't drink a plane.

I soar through the air,
well above your hair,

> Where else would you fly

At first I have need
of some serious speed.

> You need to get some speed for take-off

Later, it's nice
to be more concise.

> Later you need to slow down to properly aim and hit your target

To the club we could go
if it doesn't snow

> You could go flying if the weather is nice

If I go to the beach
You will probably screech.

> Spitfire attack on the beach would ruin anyone's day.

Comment: I like the the thought. Golf holes are called cups a lot of places though.

Answer (score 2):

You might be

> Water, Contaminated Water to be More Precise

but don't drink me up,

> Don't drink dirty water unless you want to be poisoned.

I soar through the air,

> As a cloud, I can move through the air.

well above your hair,

> Unlike fog, I always will be high in the sky

At first I have need of some serious speed.

> Storms will quickly bring a lot of rain/dirty water

Later, it's nice to be more concise.

> A little sprinkle or some fun with water in the summer is great

To the club we could go if it doesn't snow

> If it is that cold, water would turn into ice. Even water would like to stay cool.

If I go to the beach, You will probably screech

> As waves, you would scream out joy. If you forgot how to swim, you will scream with your life. If you love playing in the water like most kids, you will have lots of fun and scream with joy.

Comment: Not what I am going for, but you make a very good argument.

Comment: Looks like we have a couple of new riddlers on the site! You're both making nice contributions here :-)

Comment: Just one more rep!

Comment: Check the new second line for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

You might be

> Urine

I go in a cup,

> Urine can go in a cup if you need to be tested

but don't drink me up,

> You shouldn't drink urine

I soar through the air,

> Urine goes through the air when you urinate

well above your hair,

> OK urine doesn't really fit this clue.

At first I have need of some serious speed.

> When you start to urinate, it comes out fast.

Later, it's nice to be more concise.

> When you're about done, it slows to a trickle.

To the club we could go if it doesn't snow

> Urine doesn't fit this clue either.

If I go to the beach You will probably screech.

> If you are urinating at the beach, you probably got stung by a jellyfish and it really hurts.  Urinating on yourself supposedly eases the pain of a jellyfish sting.

Comment: Definately made me chuckle, but not quite. Please don't pee over my hair :)

Comment: You dirty-minded sod! :-p

Comment: Shouldn't drink urine?! You don't!

Comment: How does anyone even end up with that answer man?! xD Insane!

Answer (score 1):

Now I think it might be

> STEAM.

*I go in a cup, 

 but you can't drink me up,*

> A cup of tea or coffee might be steaming, but you can't drink steam.

*I soar through the air, 

 well above your hair,*

> Steam can pass by well above the level of a human head.

*At first I have need 

 of some serious speed. 

 Later, it's nice 

 to be more concise.*

> Steam might start off flowing quickly but end up dissipating in the air.

*To the club we could go

if it doesn't snow 

If I go to the beach 

 You will probably screech.*

> I haven't worked these lines out yet!

---

### First attempt

Could it be

> a STORM?

The title suggests we might be looking for something in the natural world, and

> a storm is certainly a force of nature.

*I go in a cup, 

 but you can't drink me up,*

> Refers to the well-known phrase "a storm in a teacup".

*I soar through the air, 

 well above your hair,*

> Stormclouds pass by well above the level of a human head.

*At first I have need 

 of some serious speed. 

 Later, it's nice 

 to be more concise.*

> At first I thought this was wordplay like in the OP's last riddle: I was looking for words like *fastshort*. Now I think it might be more literal: storms start off fast and violent but later calm down.

*To the club we could go*

> ???

*if it doesn't snow*

> snowstorm.

*If I go to the beach 

 You will probably screech.*

> sandstorm.

Comment: Very nice try, but not what I was looking for. The title is more of a joke this time.

Comment: @AggieKidd I've edited with another try.

Comment: Good thoughts, but still not quite.

Answer (score 1):

> Probably not the answer you are looking for, but ICE fits this riddle pretty well.

Explanation:

I go in a cup,

> ice cube

but you can't drink me up,

> you cannot drink ice

I soar through the air,
well above your hair,

> a comet has ice in it

At first I have need
of some serious speed.
Later, it's nice
to be more concise.

> something about clouds and snow

To the club we could go
if it doesn't snow
If I go to the beach
You will probably screech

Comment: It's not, but I'd love to hear your explanation of how.

Comment: I thought the same thing +1 for writing it out for me.